# Corsair K70 hanging on linux when using '/' key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, freeze

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 on a Lenovo e470 notebook on my work.

Yesterday I switched from my old lenovo usb keyboard to a corsair k70 mechanical keyboard that i brought from home.

Everything is working ok, aside from when i hit the bar key '/' (the one near the right-shift or the one in key numeric keypad, doesn't matter) the keyboard hangs for a second or two. it's VERY ANNOYING when using the terminal.

In fact, if i plug this keyboard, even the '/' key from the built-in keyboard hangs a little.

Anyone knows how to dead with this?

Comment: Discovered that if I use shift+/  AKA '?' the same hang occours

Comment: You mentioned that the hang occurs when using the built in keyboard. Can you confirm that the hang doesn't occur at all when you unplug the K70?

Comment: Yes, i can confirm. Only when the k70 is plugged in the hang occours.